# How to format monthly variable from year/month numeric variable (R)

Tags: r, date

I have a vector with numeric (not formated) year/month variable. Consider the vector below for all months of year 2012. How could I create a formated monthly variable from it?

```
ym <- c(201201,201202,201203,201204,201205,201206,201207,201208,201209,201210,201211,201212)
```

Comment: when you say `How could I create a formated monthly variable from it` can you show the expectted

Answer (score 2):

May be need

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(as.character(ym), '%Y%m'), '%b')
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
format(as.Date(paste0(ym, '01'), '%Y%m%d'), '%b')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%%`, e.g.,

```
> month.abb[ym %% 100]
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```